# Click event handler with Custom Control Button

Tags: vb.net, event-handling, asp.net-3.5, custom-controls, onclick

I'm creating an ASP.NET Custom Control for my web application which is basically an ASP.NET Button control contained inside multiple `<div>` elements (for styling purposes).

How can I create a Click event handler for my custom control so that my control acts as an ASP.NET Button?

Ie.

```
<cc:Button id="myButton" runat="server" Text="Submit" />

Sub myButton_Click(sender as object, e as EventArgs) Handles myButton.Click

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the code behind, declare an event in your class:

```
Public Event Click(sender as object, e as EventArgs)
```

Then when you handle the click event for the constinuent button, raise the event

```
Sub btnButton_Click(sender as object, e as EventArgs) Handles btnButton.Click
    RaiseEvent Me.Click(Me, EventArgs)
End Sub
```

Comment: Had to make a slight change, but apart from that, worked perfectly!

Sub btnButton_Click(sender as object, e as EventArgs) Handles btnButton.Click
    RaiseEvent Click(Me, e)
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Great snippet, came very handy for User Control to raise event where the parent screen needs to be notified. My generic form is like this:

```
Public Event eventTrigger(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

Private Sub ucUserControl_Changed(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtText1.TextChanged, txtText2.TextChanged,txtetc.TextChanged

    RaiseEvent eventTrigger(Me, e)

End Sub
```

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. Check this [metaSO question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question) and [Jon Skeet: Coding Blog](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully.aspx) on how to give a correct answer.